# Многозначность и омонимы

Tags: омонимы, лексика

Вообщем учу все по Лексике. И вот голова идет кругом! Как отличить омонимы от многозначных слов? Вот ручка дверная и ручка у человека, я так понял, это омонимы, а ручка у человека и ручка, которой писать, - это многозначность (т.к. имеют похожую форму), правильно ли это?

Помогите разобраться с этой темой. В гугле искал, ничего хорошего для себя не нашел. Но если вы найдете ссылку, где это могут разжевать, буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробую объяснить. Многозначные слова отличаются от омонимов тем, что значения **одного** слова имеют нечто общее. Например, игла швейная, игла у ежа или у елки  - в значении этих слов есть общее: острые, колются. Ключ от двери, ключ гаечный, ключ к задаче - каждый ключ что-то открывает в прямом или переносном смысле, это слова омонимы. Ключ в значении родник - ничего общего с предыдущими значениями не имеет, это **разные слова**, омонимы, полные лексические омонимы - т.е. слова совпадают во всех формах. 
 Как проверить, если сам не можешь разобраться? В толковом словаре слова омонимы располагаются в разных словарных статьях, значения слова - в одной. Теперь про ручку. Все, что Вы перечислили - это значения одного слова. Ручка у двери, мебели или пишущая - общее то, что это все берут в руку, служит опорой для рук. Ручка ребенка - уменьшительное от слова рука. Во всех объяснениях проходит эта "рука". Ручка - это многозначное слово. 
Есть еще омоформы  - разные слова совпадают в некоторых формах: стекло (сущ) и стекло (глагол в прошедшем времени) и омофоны - слова. совпадающие в устной речи (луг-лук)